# Java: Challenging Reflection - Dynamic Fields and Operators

Tags: java, dynamic, reflection, dynamic-variables

I have data modeled in tables, which when queried could return a result set like:

```
+----------+-----------------+-----------+--------+-----------+----------+-------+
| subgroup | parent_subgroup | condition | field  | field_pos | operator | value |
+----------+-----------------+-----------+--------+-----------+----------+-------+
|        0 |            NULL | OR        | Field1 |         4 | equal    | A     |
|        1 |               0 | AND       | Field2 |         9 | equal    | B     |
|        1 |               0 | AND       | Field3 |        20 | equal    | C     |
+----------+-----------------+-----------+--------+-----------+----------+-------+
```

This would evaluate to the Boolean expression:

```
Field1 = A OR (Field2 = B AND Field3 = C)
```

Basically, I'd like to manufacture lines of code which execute during runtime. Which, having just said it, sounds insane. I'd much rather be doing this in a weakly typed language like PHP, but this has to happen in Java land.

The left two columns form an adjacency list, and the field_pos indicates the index in an array of strings where the value would be compared with.

So in Java this would need to turn into:

```
String[] fields = {"1", "2", "3", ... "n"};
if (fields[4].equals("A") || (fields[9].equals("B") && fields[20].equals("C"))) {
    return true;
}
```

I assume Java reflection would help, but don't know how this could be made elegant and not full of conditionals. Any ideas?

Comment: Since you know the array, the only thing you need to map is the operator and condition and I would use a switch case/hashmap or something similar for that, then evaluate each expression bottom up, or am I missing something?

Comment: I'd like to avoid switch/conditionals. I'm actually finding a few libraries that do this sort of thing-- basically converting strings to code. Java Expression Parser seems to be pretty much in line with what I have in mind. [Here's](https://github.com/uklimaschewski/EvalEx) one I think might be useful.

Comment: Yes, Java Expression Parser is an implementation of the [Interpreter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern).  That's what I would recommend if you want something flexible that changes on the fly.  Note that this is exactly what other libraries do.  A JDBC driver is an interpreter/bridge pattern.

Comment: One problem here I see is that you have no way to express order of terms.  In your example, `AND` is commutative but some algebraic operators are not.  Subtraction and division for example.

Comment: Conditions will just be ands and ors. No DeMorgan's to contend with :)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using GroovyShell. Here's my sandbox:

```
package com.jonas.groovy;

import groovy.lang.Binding;
import groovy.lang.GroovyShell;

public class GroovySandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String toEvaluate = "'string' == 'string' && ('string' == 'String' || 'a' == 'N' || true)";
        System.out.println(evalFilter(toEvaluate));
        toEvaluate = "Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.WEDNESDAY";
        System.out.println(evalFilter(toEvaluate));
    }

    public static boolean evalFilter(String expression){
        GroovyShell shell=new GroovyShell(new Binding());
        Object value=shell.evaluate(expression);
        if (!(value instanceof Boolean)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Boolean value expected out of expression: " + expression);
        }
        return (Boolean)value;
    }
}
```